# How do I see object values when debugging terraform

Tags: terraform

When writing a terraform module I often run in errors like this:

```
Error: Invalid index

  on ../../../modules/host/main.tf line 7, in resource "aws_network_interface" "host":
   7:   subnet_id = data.aws_subnet_ids.current[each.key].ids[0]
    |----------------
    | data.aws_subnet_ids.current is object with 2 attributes
    | each.key is "lab"
```

There are all kinds of reasons why this happens. Usually it is because what I think a certain object will contain is incorrect.

In order to help debugging this it would be usefull to at least see what the object contains. "Object with 2 attributes" is rather vague. I would like to know what attribtues it has, so I can add the necessary transformations to end up with the string I need here.

So is there a way? Can you in some way run "terraform plan" in such that the contents of those objects are actually displayed when the plan runs in to an error?

Answer (score 7):

You can run "terraform console" command and put directly  your expressions.
eg. Suppose for given map in variable file you want to see flattened list.

```
variable "podmap" {
   type  = "map"
   default = {
       dev = ["pod1", "pod6"]
       qa =  ["pod5"]
       uat = ["pod5"]
       testenv = []
  }
}
```

Run terraform console:

```
$ terraform console
> flatten([for podtype, podlist in var.podmap : [for podname in podlist : { name = podname, type = podtype }]])flatten([for podtype, podlist in var.podmap : [for podname in podlist : { name = podname, type = podtype }]])
```

Based on your expression/statement it will give you output accordingly.

for above flatten function you will get below output list which you cannot see while you do terraform plan.

```
[
  {
    "name" = "pod5"
    "type" = "dev"
  },
  {
    "name" = "pod6"
    "type" = "dev"
  },
  {
    "name" = "pod5"
    "type" = "qa"
  },
  {
    "name" = "pod5"
    "type" = "uat"
  },
]
```

Comment: To generalize, just load up `terraform console` and enter your map/variable name to see what it shows, if nothing back off one level etc.

Answer (score 2):

**** Warning: this could potentially write sensitive data to disk, use with caution ****

To see the contents of an object create a temporary local_file resource and set it's content property to the object converted to json. It will then be displayed in the plan. Once you are done remove the resource. For example:

```
resource "local_file" "this" {
    content  = jsonencode(your object)
    filename = "a valid file path"
}
```

Answer (score -2):

This turned to be actually easier than I expected.

Just do:

```
terraform refresh
terraform show
```

And you will see what all current data sources contain.

It would have been convenient if this possibility was hinted at under the debugging chapter of the docs...

Comment: I'm assuming the reason for all the downvotes is because `terraform show` doesn't output runtime object values. As stated in the documentation (https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/commands/show.html):

`The terraform show command is used to provide human-readable output from a state or plan file. This can be used to inspect a plan to ensure that the planned operations are expected, or to inspect the current state as Terraform sees it.`

... so yeah, I also downvoted this answer.

Comment: I don't think this is a bad answer at all, differnet situations call for different things. Upvoted!